# Modifying XML views in ViewPager using Java

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In my android app I am using `ViewPager` to navigate between 4 `XML`. Following is the code used.

```
package com.win.kora;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Htpnew extends Activity
{
private ViewPager viewPager;

private LinearLayout page1;
private LinearLayout page2;
private LinearLayout page3;
private LinearLayout page4;
private TextView tv2, tv3, tv4, tv6, tv7, tv8;
private SurfaceView sv;
private Canvas c;
private Paint paint= new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG), paint1= new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.htpnew);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new MainPageAdapter());

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Htpnew.this, "page " + (position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {

        }
    });     

}

class MainPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position)
    {
        View page = null;
        switch (position)
        {
        case 0:
            if (page1 == null)
            {
                page1 = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(Htpnew.this).inflate(R.layout.page_one, null);

            }
            page = page1;
            break;
        case 1:
            if (page2 == null)
            {
                page2 = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(Htpnew.this).inflate(R.layout.page_two, null);
            }
            page = page2;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (page3 == null)
            {
                page3 = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(Htpnew.this).inflate(R.layout.page_three, null);

            }
            page = page3;
            break;
        default:
            if (page4 == null)
            {
                page4 = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(Htpnew.this).inflate(R.layout.page_four, null);
            }
            page = page4;
            break;
        }

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);

        return page;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view)
    {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }


}

}
```

However, I want to make changes in these XML using java, like changing background color of a textview etc - for eg,
`tv8=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv8);                                 GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) tv8.getBackground();
gd.setColor(0xFFFF0000);`

Even there is a surfaceview on which some drawing has to be done based on user input. Such changes are required in all the 4 XML. Where this code has to be placed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the code to change background (or modifying any part of the view) inside the adapter. To find a particular TextView you could use

```
case 2:
        if (page3 == null)
        {
            page3 = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(Htpnew.this).inflate(R.layout.page_three, null);

        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)page3.findViewById(R.id.tv8);
        // modify text view here
        page = page3;
        break;
```

Comment: So does this modification takes place everytime user swipes to that page  ?

Comment: If you want to change the view content after it has been generated once, you'll need to call adapter.notifydatasetchanged() after modifying required data, otherwise it'll return the same view that was generated initially.

Comment: actually the first page is having a surfaceview on which i am drawing with a random colour. the colour is not changed is i swipe to next page and come back, it changes, however, if i swipe to next two pages and come back. what is happening, i do not want the color to be changed ?